# Would Matthew 25:27 have communicated usury?

Tags: matthew, context

How would Jesus’s 1st century Jewish audience react to the activity described in Matthew 25 verse 27? Would they have associated this with “usery” as forbidden by Jewish custom or would this have been a common and accepted form of investment?

> Matt 25:17 - Therefore it behooved you to put my money to the bankers,
> and having come, I would have received my own with interest.

Comment: It's a parable with general content of how humans negotiate with one another. The parable, itself, is not stating whether the activity is moral or not : only that it took place. I don't see the relevance of the question.

Comment: After the Master reveals his character to be unjust, affirming: “I reap where I have not sown and gather where I scattered no seed” I think then how the Master dictates the use of his money would further inform the listeners as to how to perceive this narrative … that’s the relevance of my question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us define "usury" as interest charged that illegal or unethical as defined by the Torah - see appendix below.

The Torah does not forbid interest charged in deposit money, either at a commercial institution (eg, a legally established "bank" or equivalent) or from loans to foreigners.

The parable of the talents in Matt 25:14-30 appears to allude to interest gained on deposit money at a commercial institution(s).  This is not forbidden by Torah law.  The point at which interest became illegal (under Torah law) occurs when interest is charged either to the poor or a fellow Jew.

[Note:  For completeness only, I note that the word translated "banker" in Matt 25:27 - is "trapezités"  from the root word, "trapeza" denoting a person who sat on a bench to exchange money.  Our English word "bank" comes from the Middle English and French meaning a bench denoting a money changer which thus sat.  Hence, the Greek "trapeza" and our English word "bank" have very similar origins and meanings.]

**APPENDIX - Torah on "Usury"**

- Ex 22:25 - If you lend money to **one of My people among you who is poor**, you must not act as a creditor to him; you are not to charge him interest.
- Lev 25:35-37 - Now if your countryman becomes **destitute** and cannot support himself among you, then you are to help him as you would a foreigner or stranger, so that he can continue to live among you. Do not take any interest or profit from him, but fear your God, that your countryman may live among you. You must not lend him your silver at interest or sell him your food for profit.
- Deut 23:19, 20 - Do not charge **your brother** interest on money, food, or any other type of loan. You may charge a foreigner interest, but not your brother, so that the LORD your God may bless you in everything to which you put your hand in the land that you are entering to possess.

Thus, the Torah defined interest as illegal, and thus usury under the following circumstances:

- when charged to the poor and destitute
- when levied against a fellow Israelite

Israelites were explicitly allowed to charge interest on foreign loans as shown above.

Comment: Would it also help knowing that the interest rate is set by the "banker", and not by the person investing the money?

Comment: @RayButterworth - good point; a commercial institution is also more impersonal as well whose rules are publicly known and understood.  Such money changers were essential then and now for exchanging currencies in international trade.

Comment: It's not illegal to charge interest to the poor or destitute, but the poor or destitute of God's people or your fellow Israelite countryman. The prohibition was initially only against poor or destitute Israelites, but then got expanded to all Israelites.

Comment: τραπεζίταις plays another pivotal role in the temple.